# Looping and sorting email items

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to loop in a vba script in Outlook in ascending mode.

I tried several ways but it seems it always loop in descending mode.

Is there a faster way to loop through the email items?

Thanks.
The code is something like:

```
Public Sub CheckClient()
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim items As Outlook.items
Dim strFind As String
Dim Item

Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder()

strFind = "[ReceivedTime] >= '05/15/2017' AND [ReceivedTime] < '05/16/2017'"

Set items = objFolder.items
items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

Set items = objFolder.items.Restrict(strFind)

For Each Item In objFolder.items
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then

            If Item.Sender = "Client1"  Then
                DBInsert (Item)
            End if
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You reverted to processing the "raw" items in the folder rather than the items in the collection. True/False has no impact on the items in the folder.

```
Sub CheckClient()

Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim items As Outlook.items

Dim strFind As String
Dim Item As Object
Dim resItems As items

Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder()

strFind = "[ReceivedTime] >= '05/15/2017' AND [ReceivedTime] < '05/16/2017'"

Set items = objFolder.items

items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
For Each Item In items
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        Debug.Print Item.ReceivedTime & ": " & Item.Subject
    End If
Next

Debug.Print

Set resItems = objFolder.items.Restrict(strFind)
' False should sort in reverse order of True
resItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False

' Process resItems not the entire folder
For Each Item In resItems
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
        Debug.Print Item.ReceivedTime & ": " & Item.Subject
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> *for ascending and faster way to loop through the email items*-

*Try using reverse loop, also Restrict `SenderName` with your filter ( `strFind` ) to speed it up*

*Example would be*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CheckClient()
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim Recived As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set objFolder = Application.Session.PickFolder
    Set Items = objFolder.Items
        Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"

    strFind = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                        Chr(34) & " >= '05/15/2017' AND " & _
                        Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                        Chr(34) & " < '05/16/2017' AND " & _
                        Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname" & _
                        Chr(34) & "Like '%Client1%'"

    Set Items = objFolder.Items.Restrict(strFind)

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        Debug.Print Items(i).SenderName 'Immediate Window
        Debug.Print Items(i).ReceivedTime 'Immediate Window
    Next

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
End Sub
```

*Make sure to update **`%Client1%`** with correct name*