# Read most recent 100 lines of an Outlook inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

This script moves email from Joe Smith and Wally Gator to the _ALERTS folder.

It is slow. I think it reads through the whole inbox (which is huge).

Would there be a way to read the first 100 lines in an already sorted by descending inbox?

```
Sub MoveItems()
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object    

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myItems = myInbox.Items
Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("_ALERTS")
Dim varSearchTerm As Variant: For Each varSearchTerm 
In Array("Joe Smith", "Wally Gator")
Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = '" & varSearchTerm & "'")
    While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Move myDestFolder
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
    Wend
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003384/looping-and-sorting-email-items `items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True` and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57391257/trying-to-move-emails-in-a-loop-but-not-all-get-moved-in-the-first-run `For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1` change `Items.Count` to 100.

Answer (score 0):

Limit search to most recent 100 items

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MoveItemsWithLimit()

Dim myInbox As folder
Dim myDestFolder As folder
Dim myItems As Items
Dim myItem As Object

Dim varSearchTerm As Variant
Dim i As Long

Dim limitMax As Long
Dim limit As Long

Set myInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set myDestFolder = myInbox.folders("_ALERTS")

limitMax = 100

For Each varSearchTerm In Array("Joe Smith", "Wally Gator")

    ' New collection of current inbox items for each varSearchTerm
    ' Else the second collection
    '  will include moved items from the first collection
    '  and will generate a not found error
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items

    ' VBA does not recognize GUI sort
    ' Sort the myItems collection, not myInbox.Items
    myItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

    ' Limit to recent items
    If myItems.Count < limitMax Then
        limit = myItems.Count
    Else
        limit = limitMax
    End If

    For i = limit To 1 Step -1 ' Move or delete in reverse

        Set myItem = myItems(i)
        'Debug.Print myItem.ReceivedTime

        ' This test is usually done in a postive way
        '  to check for emails only
        ' Apply the <> Nothing test if warranted
        'If TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing" Then

        If LCase(TypeName(myItem)) = LCase("MailItem") Then

            If myItem.senderName = varSearchTerm Then
                Debug.Print myItem.senderName
                myItem.Move myDestFolder
                'Debug.Print "Moved: " & myItem.Subject

                ' possible miniscule increase in efficiency
                '  since there are less most recent items
                '  to include in the next collection
                limitMax = limitMax - 1

            End If

        End If

    Next

Next

End Sub
```